# Verify a cloned contract

Tags: etherscan, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, verify, contract-verification

I want to deploy a contract via the clone factory pattern described [here](https://soliditydeveloper.com/clonefactory)

Is there a way to verify the child cloned contract (preferably via CLI) on etherscan? I know for proxy contracts generally it was only possible via the etherscan interface directly.

It also mentions this but not sure if this holds:

> Etherscan verification doesn't work yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hardhat-etherscan](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan) task to verify contracts on etherscan and co.

Put the source code of the contract in `contracts` folder. Compile it with `npx hardhat compile`. Configurate the Etherscan's task by defining the API Key.

```bash
npx hardhat verify --network mainnet 0xAddress
```

It fetches the ByteCode of the Contract and if it matches one of the compiled contracts, then the source code will be uploaded to the Etherscan.

With the plugin, you can also set the constructor arguments, which were used to create the contract.

> If the arguments are complex, the `hardhat-etherscan` requires additional `js` module, which exports those values. But you can also automate the creation of that module file.

Comment: but does this work specifically with proxy contracts? The verification isn't as straightforward as for regular contracts (ie the process you described).

Comment: Actually, the proxy contract verification is the same as the regular contracts. If you mean, the `Proxy` Tab is missing, means Etherscan couldn't automatically detect current implementation address. Then you just have to call the API manually. https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts#verifying-proxy-contract-using-curl It triggers automatic detection again, _optionally you can provide the expected implementation address_.